# What is the right way to show up images at R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am doing an html document from R Markdown (RStudio) and I think I am following the right instructions to show it up. I read the R's Bookdown (https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown) and there says this is the way, or at least this is what I get from it. I am using this only script line to make the image calling:

`![Hadley Wickham](Macintosh HD/Usuarios/ivanmendivelso/Dropbox/Escuela/IntroR Vids/HW.jpeg).`

When knitting I get this error message: "File Macintosh HD/Usuarios/ivanmendivelso/Dropbox/Escuela/IntroR Vids/HW.jpeg not found in resource path
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 99
Execution halted".
Does anybody know what am I doing wrong? Why I can not see images in my documents?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your file location seems wrong, double check it via finder.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your path is not correct.

If the image can be moved, put it in the same directory as your .Rmd file.  If you can't move it to the file directory and if you don't speak UNIX, you can get the path by:

1. Finding the file with the finder
2. Right click on it
3. hold the option key on your keyboard and you will see the menu change from *Copy "HW.jpg"* to say *Copy "HW.jpeg" as pathname*

Paste that path into your code.

Answer (score 0):

When you have file spaces in your file path you need to put single quotes around to make them strings

`![Hadley Wickham](‘Macintosh HD’/Usuarios/ivanmendivelso/Dropbox/Escuela/‘IntroR Vids’/HW.jpeg)`

What about this below

```
![Hadley Wickham](/Macintosh HD/Usuarios/ivanmendivelso/Dropbox/Escuela/IntroR Vids/HW.jpeg).
```

notice the `/` at the begining of the file path. on Mac the very first `/` is meaning from the root of your hard drive

Comment: I put `'` and still does not work, is it a different kind of single quote?

Comment: We might have different languages. Try double braces “” or copy my character and see if that helps

Comment: I think you are right, I tried copying these characters and I yields error also, so I guess we are talking about different languages, I am using R and its interface RStudio. Thanks for your time and support :)

Comment: I ment different keyboard language layouts